# want to insert average values in to average table only year 2008 from regular values

Tags: mysql, sql

want to insert average values in to average table only year 2008 from regular values table as a average  but code has error how i overcome. without "where year(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))= 2008" query work well

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `clima_data`.`avg_month_val1`  ( `year` , `month` ,  `evep` , `sunshine_hrs` , `rainfall` , `max_temp` , `min_temp` ) 

SELECT year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as year,
       month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))as month,
       round(avg(evep),2) ,      
       round(Avg(sunshine_hrs),2),
       round(sum(rainfall),2),
       round(AVG(max_temp),2) ,
       round(avg(min_temp),2) 
 FROM reg_data3
 GROUP BY year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')),
          month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) 
 WHERE year(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))= 2008 
 ORDER BY 1 Desc
```

Comment: please do mention which DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do

```
 
  WHERE year(date)= 2008
  GROUP BY year(date), month(date)
```

instead of

```
 GROUP BY year(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d')),
          month(str_to_date(date, '%Y-%m-%d'))
 WHERE year(DATE_FORMAT(date, '%y-%m-%d'))= 2008
```

The **Year** function will automatically do the conversion for you and you'll benefit from the speed too.

Answer (score 0):

I notice one possible problem here (would be easier to direct you better if you specify the errors you get):
The WHERE clause should appear before the GROUP BY clause (at least in most DBMS).
I believe that if you switch between them, it should work.